IntegrityError sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: store_items.name
I removed the unique constraint from the table class but I'm gettting unique constraint failed when I try to add data to the table of same name present in the table.
class Store(db.Model):
 __tablename__ = "store_items"
 id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
 name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(250), nullable=False)
 item1: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, nullable=False)
 item2: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, nullable=False)
 item3: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, nullable=False)
 total: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, nullable=False)

I removed the unique constraint but it's still not working

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I believe you need to  Generate a new migration script. but there is not enough information to say anything certainly.
